# UnityEditor.SceneAsset class not accessible in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, addressables

I am new to unity addressables and would like to load a scene with an AssetReference. To enforce AssetReferences being a scene, I created the following class in a utility assembly:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;

[Serializable]
public sealed class SceneReference : AssetReferenceT<SceneAsset>
{
    public SceneReference(string guid) : base(guid) { }
}
```

JetBrains Rider then said SceneAsset had to be referenced from assembly: `UnityEditor.CoreModule`. I used its suggestion, and Rider automatically set up the
assembly reference. Everything worked great, and indeed I could only drag scenes into a `SceneReference` field.

But everything broke down when I went to make a build. I get four errors:

1:`Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 139.`

2:`Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors`

3:`Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 11 seconds (11360 ms) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)`

4:`UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94  UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)`

I have tried to manually locate assembly `UnityEditor.CoreModule` and reference it in my utility assembly's `assembly definition asset` but couldn't find it. It still works great in the editor but won't compile for a build. If anyone has a solution or at least knows why this isn't working, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SceneAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) indeed can not be in a build and only exists within the Unity Editor - for what reason ever.

It is a special case of an asset that only exists in editor since later on in a build the scenes are handled completely different as runtime [`Scene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html).

The entire [`UnityEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html) namespace is completely stripped of in a build.

---

For serialization the best option is usually to serialize and store the asset path and later use that for loading the scene.

---

You can still make scenes Addressables though and load them via the usual more manual Addressables route e.g. using a "normal" generic

```
public AssetReference Scene;
```

See [Addressables - Scene Loading](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/addressables-scene-loading).